# Differential equations with applications and historical notes 3rd edition chapter 4 problem 3 (a)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recreational-mathematics

Problem 3.

A bright young executive with foresight but no initial capital makes
constant investments of D dollars per year at an annual interest rate of
100k percent. Assume that the investments are made continuously and
that interest is compounded continuously.

(a) Find the accumulated amount A at any time t.

Answer in the book :

$A = D(e^{kt}-1)/k$

I fail to get this answer with my calculation.
I attempted to solve this problem with A (accumulated investment result)

as a function of x ( money invested per year. $dx/dt=D$ ) and t (time as year)

Within the textbook, Example 1 Continuously compounded interest (page 20),

Quote,

> More generally, if P is money deposited in a bank and if the interest
> rate is 100k percent (k = 0.06 for 6 percent),
> and if this interest is
> compounded n times a year, then after t years the accumulated amount
> is
>
> $A=P(1+k/n)^{nt}$ Since this is continuous investment, n approaches to infinity.
>
> Hence $A=Pe^{kt}$

I attempted A as a function of x and t.

$A=f(x,t)$

and change of money invested per year $dx/xt=D$

And since $A=xe^{kt}$ ,

$A=Dte^{kt}$

My answer satisfies initial condition. ($A=0$ when $x=0$ and $A=0$ when $t=0$)

But it doesn't match the answer in the textbook.

Comment: The equation you use for your answer assumes P is constant. More specifically, you should try solving $\frac{\partial A}{\partial t} = D+kA$ instead, because this equation takes in the compounding of the amount invested, ($kA$) and the extra money added $D$. From there, you should get the textbook answer

Comment: I appreciate your insight. But when I try to solve your formula with D and k as constants, I get $A=Dt + k\int Adt$ But textbook answer has a form of $A=ae^{kt}+b$ with a and b as constants. I can't solve the remaining $Dt$. What does my inferior brain do wrong here?

Comment: Yeah, this question seems to be posted a few chapters too early in the book. If you want an answer, try reading up on integrating factors. I can also post a full answer below if you're curious

Comment: Please do so. I should try to solve problems after I read this book through without trying to solve problems I guess. Then on my second read I should start solving problems. But now I can't get this problem away from my head and it seems next problem isn't easier. Relieve me. :0

Comment: Thanks for this initiating this discussion. What is the title of your textbook ?

Comment: @Duchamp Gérard H. E. Differential equations with applications and historical notes 3rd edition By George F. Simmons.

Comment: @A student  I am going to the text in order to get more context. Thanks.

Comment: My greatest mistake here is the fact that I underestimated the subject of this textbook. The Differential Equation. The Author is kind enough to show me all the possibilities and histories what the related knowledge is made from. But I shouldn't have tried to achieve this subject by one single attempt just like other mathematics subjects. I will read the contents through first then I will come back to the first page and start to try to solve problems.

Comment: @mode_er if you could show me how to solve this problem I sincerely appreciate. (whether you do so or not.) I am mentally too exhausted by trying to solve what I couldn't. I will check back later. Thank you for guidance.

Comment: @Astudent done!

Answer (score 1):

As per user request, I'll post a complete solution here. Based on my comment, let's start with:

$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial t} = D + kA$$

$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial t} -kA= D $$

The theory behind an integrating factor is that we multiply each term by $\rho$ and get

$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial t} \rho(t) -kA \rho(t)= D \rho(t)$$

and then try to use the chain rule in reverse where

$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial t} \rho(t) -kA\rho(t) = \frac{\partial} {\partial t}(A *\rho(t)) $$ By expanding the right hand side with the chain rule, we get

$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial t} \rho(t) -kA\rho(t) = \frac{\partial A}{\partial t} \rho(t)+\rho^{'}(t)A $$

Thus,

$$\rho^{'}(t) A = -k A \rho(t)$$

$$\frac{\rho^{'}(t)}{\rho(t)}=-k $$

The solution to this equation is just

$$\rho(t) = e^{-kt}$$

Going back to our initial equation, we get

$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial t} e^{-kt} -kA e^{-kt}= D e^{-kt}$$

Integrating each side, we get

$$A e^{-kt} = \frac{-De^{-kt}}{k} + C$$

$$A = \frac{-D}{k} + C e^{kt}$$

To meet the initial condition, we set $C=\frac{D}{k}$ and get

$$A = \frac{De^{kt}}{k} -\frac{D}{k} = \frac{D(e^{kt}-1)}{k}$$

Comment: I just came back from work. Thank you very much Mr. mode_er! Unfortunately my reputation is too low to upvote. Someone please upvote his answer. I will revisit when I can upvote later. I will study your answer now. :)

Comment: Brilliant! And there was no way I could get this done by myself just by reading the textbook up to that page. I really should read through the book once and then re-read and try to solve the problems. :)